# Node search is not working in test kitchen

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am not geeting output and error

> ------Exception-------
>
> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>
> Message: 1 actions failed."

cookbook/test/integration/nodes
 Json file

```
{
  "id": "hive server", 
  "chef_type": "node", 
  "environment": "dev", 
  "json_class": "Chef::Node", 
  "run_list": [], 
  "automatic": { 
      "hostname": "test.net", 
      "fqdn": "127.0.0.1", 
      "name": "test.net", 
      "ipaddress": "127.0.0.1", 
      "node_zone": "green", 
      "roles": []
  },
  "attributes": {
      "hiveserver": "true"
  }
}
```

Recipe

```
hiveNodes = search(:node, "hiveserver:true AND      environment:node.environment AND node_color:node["node_color"])

# hiveserverList = ""
# hiveNodes.each |hnode| do
# hiveserverList += hnode
#end

#file '/tmp/test.txt' do
#  content '#{hiveserverList}'
#end
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Maybe add some prose to explain

Comment: Node search from test kitchen failing

Comment: In test kitchen I want to search the dummy nodes depend on tags attributes which are from nodes.json file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node search is giving nothing in test kitchen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543383/node-search-is-giving-nothing-in-test-kitchen)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be using `"hiveserver:true AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND node_color:#{node["node_color"]}"` as your search string. The `#{}` syntax is how you embed a Ruby expression value in to a string. Also for reasons of complex backwards compat, the environment on a node is called `chef_environment`.